# Adding multiple views issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipageviewcontroller, slide

I made a `slideView` myself. It's just a small `UIPageViewController` Inside of it, there is a `UILabel` and I keep adding values to it by using a timer. But I realized that when I add new values into the `slideView`, it doesn't remove the old views. It adds the new label on the old one. It's really interesting. It also causes high usage of memory. How can I remove the old one and add the new one?

Here is my code :

```
func createSlide() ->[CountdownView]{
    var slideAll = [CountdownView]()

    for i in 0..<countdownDatas.count{
        slideAll.append(Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CountdownView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CountdownView)

        slideAll[i].countdownLabel.text = "\(countdownDatas[i].month)\(countdownDatas[i].week)\(countdownDatas[i].day)\(countdownDatas[i].hour)\(countdownDatas[i].minute)\(countdownDatas[i].second)"
    }
    return slideAll

}
```

You can see the problem on this picture :
[image]

I realized that when I did clear background color for the view and the label.

SOLUTION :

Thanks to @ReinierMelian, I found the solution. Here is the working code :

```
    func createSlide() ->[CountdownView]{
        if firstTimeSlideViewSetup == true{
            firstTimeSlideViewSetup = false
            for i in 0..<countdownDatas.count{
                slideAll.append(Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CountdownView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CountdownView)

                slideAll[i].countdownLabel.text = "\(countdownDatas[i].month)\(countdownDatas[i].week)\(countdownDatas[i].day)\(countdownDatas[i].hour)\(countdownDatas[i].minute)\(countdownDatas[i].second)"
}
        }else{
            for i in 0..<countdownDatas.count{

                slideAll[i].countdownLabel.text = "\(countdownDatas[i].month)\(countdownDatas[i].week)\(countdownDatas[i].day)\(countdownDatas[i].hour)\(countdownDatas[i].minute)\(countdownDatas[i].second)"

            }
        }

        return slideAll

    }
```

Basically, when I create the `slideView` at the first time, I say that I created this and then I'm checking if there is a `slideView` or not. And then I'm just adding new values to the labels.

Comment: `slideAll.append` should be added once and then access its `countdownLabel ` and change text.

Comment: but I don't use just one page. I create more than once because I have so many pages that I'm adding to the pageviewcontroller and I'm refreshing.

Comment: then you need to check if your countdown view is already there you don´t need to add it again

Comment: did you need to show count down based on target date?

Comment: didn't you forget the closing brackets before the "return slideAll" ?

Comment: sorry for the bracket @RuslanSerebriakov. Yeah, it has a bracket in my code, but I just deleted accidentally here when I copied.

Comment: @ReinierMelian It's a countdown. So I need to add every second. That's why I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: You can update it with a timer, and avoid add over and over again a label, even without a timer if your label was added you only need update it @winnervswinner

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks. First, I thought there was no way to just refresh the label. So I flagged your answer because of that and I can't take it back lol. My apologies sir. I just realized that you were right and I just found the solution as you said. Thanks for helping! I hope you forgive me :D

Comment: @winnervswinner if you have solve it then I am pleased, your welcome, and happy coding dude!